# Test app on iOS 6 simulator on Yosemite

Tags: xcode, xcode5, ios-simulator

I've downloaded Xcode 5.1.1, and when I tried to install iOS 6.0 Simulator, I get an error:
"Could not download and install iOS 6.0 Simulator. The package “iPhoneSimulatorSDK6_0.pkg” is untrusted."

iOS 6.1 Simulator downloaded and installed successfully but when I run I get an error:
"iOS Simulator failed to install the application." Hitting "Reset Content and Settings" in the Simulator doesn't help.

I also have installed latest Xcode 6.3.1. How can I test my applications on iOS 6.0 or 6.1?

Answer (score 1):

The iOS 6.0 Simulator runtime will not work on OS X Yosemite.  It is incompatible with the host OS.

Comment: Bummer, do you know about 6.1?

Comment: iOS 7.1 and later are supported on OS X Yosemite.  iOS 6.1 and later are supported on OS X Mavericks.